# Google Chart:Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string error

Tags: javascript, arrays, debugging, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts and keep getting an error: Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string. I believe it's because in the array I'm passing in, there are string values where there should be number values. My array is n columns by 8 rows. All values on the first row should be numbers and well as all values in the first column should be string and the rest numbers. I'm grabbing all the values from the query string and when I split them they're coming through as string I believe.

Here's my URL query string: `1=Day,04/01/2013,04/08/2013,04/15/2013,04/22/2013,04/29/2013,05/06/2013&2=Monday,100,100,100,100,100,100&3=Tuesday,100,100,100,100,100,100&4=Wednesday,100,100,100,100,100,100&5=Thursday,100,100,100,100,100,100&6=Friday,100,100,100,100,100,100&7=Saturday,100,100,100,100,100,100&8=Sunday,100,100,100,100,100,100`

And here's my javascript:

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

var row1 = getUrlVars()["1"];
var row2 = getUrlVars()["2"];
var row3 = getUrlVars()["3"];
var row4 = getUrlVars()["4"];
var row5 = getUrlVars()["5"];
var row6 = getUrlVars()["6"];
var row7 = getUrlVars()["7"];
var row8 = getUrlVars()["8"];

var row1x=row1.split(","); 
var row2x=row2.split(","); 
var row3x=row3.split(","); 
var row4x=row4.split(","); 
var row5x=row5.split(","); 
var row6x=row6.split(","); 
var row7x=row7.split(","); 
var row8x=row8.split(","); 

var items = [row1x, row2x, row3x,row4x,row5x,row6x,row7x,row8x];



      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(items);

        var options = {
          title: 'Members AM Open Rate'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

Any thought on how to force all values not in the first row or column to numbers instead of strings?

Answer (score 0):

> Any thought on how to force all values not in the first row or column to numbers instead of strings?

Use separate arrays:

```
var headers = [row1x];
var items = [row2x, row3x, row4x, row5x, row6x, row7x, row8x];
```

and stringify and parse the array to convert numeric strings to numbers:

```
/* Take the string, create an array, create a string, replace the quotes, return array */
var row3x = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("3=Tuesday,100,100,100,100,100".split(",")).replace(/"(\d+)"/g,"$1"))
```

then concat the two arrays:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(header.concat(items) );
```